# Convert interface to float32 in go

Tags: go, types, floating-point

Using type assertion doesn't work to convert interface{} to float32

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var i interface{}
    i = 1.1
    num, ok := i.(float32)
    fmt.Println(ok)
    fmt.Println(num)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/iEJWLbBCHs8

This prints false and 0. How can I convert interface{} to float32?

Comment: `i = float32(1.1)`.   Otherwise how the compiler know you want float32? Literal 1.1 is untyped.

Comment: @mgagnon the interface{} value is from user input, so idk if that it is 1.1 or something else beforehand. I try num := float32(i) has this error: cannot convert i (type interface {}) to type float32: need type assertion

Comment: You can do this. https://play.golang.org/p/OPiXEAWvEVl . But do you absolutely need a float32? As cd1 says on its answer, float64 is the default floating point type in go, so asserting to float64 would works in your minimal example.

Answer (score 3):

When the code runs:

```
i = 1.1
```

It assigns a `float64` value to the variable `i`; that's the default type for decimal number literals in Go. When you try to convert it to `float32`, it fails because that's not the underlying type of `i`.

If you want to convert `i` to `float32`, you need to put a `float32` value in it:

```
i = float32(1.1)
```

And the conversion will succeed. If you want to be able to convert to `float32` or `float64`, you can try converting to both types, and if the conversion to `float64` succeeds, you then convert the result to `float32`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question:

> How can I convert interface{} to float32?

Not at all.

All you can do is store a float32 in an interface{} and then type-assert it out back again. The problem with your code is that you do not store a float32.